SwiftUI View Not Updating wit from ViewModel
I have a RunningCommandView where I run a command on macOS and observe the outputs to display them on the screen. However, the view is not updating with the outputs. I added a button to manually append an output to the array, and when I clicked the button, the output appeared on the screen as expected.
Goal
I want the view to automatically update and display the outputs as they are added to the array in the ViewModel.
Problem
The view does not render the outputs in real-time as they are appended to the output array in the ViewModel.
Expected Result
The view should automatically update and display new outputs as they are appended to the outputs array.
Actual Result
The view only updates when the button is clicked to manually add an output.
What I've Tried

Ensuring MainActor context when appending to the outputs array.

Using DispatchQueue.main.async for appending to the outputs array.

Moving the append logic directly to the view instead of the ViewModel.


Here is the code for the view and view model:
struct RunningCommandView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: RunningCommandViewModel = RunningCommandViewModel()
    @Binding var projectId: UUID?
    
    init(projectId: Binding<UUID?>) {
        self._projectId = projectId
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(viewModel.outputs, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text("\(value)")
                }
            }
            .background(.black)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
            
            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.outputs.append("Manual Output Test")
            }) {
                Text("Add Test Output")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.start(
                modelContext: modelContext,
                projectId: self.projectId
            )
        }
    }
}

class RunningCommandViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var project: Project?
    @Published var outputs: [String] = []
    
    var modelContext: ModelContext?
    var projectId: UUID?
    
    init() {
        self.project = nil
    }
    
    func start(modelContext: ModelContext, projectId: UUID?) {
        self.modelContext = modelContext
        self.projectId = projectId
        
        guard projectId != nil else {
            print("Cannot create the view model without an uuid")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try fetchProject()
            Task {
                try await executeCommand()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func executeCommand() throws -> Void {
        guard let project = self.project else {
            print("Cannot run a command without a project")
            return
        }
        
        if let environment = project.environments?.first {
            environment.selectedCommand?.execute { output in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.outputs.append(output)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func fetchProject() throws -> Void {
        guard let modelContext = self.modelContext else {
            print("Cannot fetch projects without a context")
            return
        }
        
        guard let projectId = self.projectId else {
            print("Cannot create the view model without an uuid")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Project>(
                predicate: #Predicate { $0.id == projectId }
            )
            
            let projects = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
            
            if let project = projects.first {
                self.project = project
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    
}

Error Messages
No error messages are displayed; the view simply does not update as expected.

You should never use @ObservedObject where you own the object. You should use @StateObject

Ohhh I can't believe that was it!!! Thank you

In SwiftUI View structs are view model and it’s .task for async/await. Also self isn’t a valid ForEach id.
